# How to dynamically draw image for button in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, drawing

This is the result I need to accomplish:

[image]

I need the icons with basic image: **basket** and additionally I need to put there UILabel with some text: once it is just a number, and once it is an amount to pay.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my example:

```
var image = UIImage(named: "cart")!
let text = "1 PLN"

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(80, 50))
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)
label.text = text
label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10)
label.sizeToFit()

let width = max(label.frame.size.width + 10, 15)
let height = CGFloat(15)

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.greenColor().CGColor)
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width,     image.size.height))

image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(80/2-50/2, 0, 50, 50))

let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectMake(75-width, 45-height, width, height), cornerRadius: 5)
path.lineWidth = 2
UIColor.redColor().setStroke()
UIColor.yellowColor().setFill()
path.stroke()
path.fill()

let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10.0), NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle]
(text as NSString).drawInRect(CGRectMake(75-width, 45-height, width, height), withAttributes: attributes)

let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

The result is following:

[image]

Some examples for different text:

[image]
[image]